# Get bbox of svg element before render or at least without flickering

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have a need to have some text scale in ways only SVG can as far as I could find. The text will change frequently so it also needs to adapt to that.

I'm making the app in react and would like to know how to calculate the bbox of an SVG (initially and every time it changes) before rendering it or at least without flickering / layout shift.

An example could be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bbox-svg-text-contain-fill-rxjh1h?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx) - the current issue is that it flicker. Everything else works fine more or less.

I've seen some other questions that are similar or nearly identical - however they do not have the requirement of changing text so it's possible to compute the bounding box in advance once or at least a one time flicker is not a big issue. Another question / thread also used a class component that supposedly updated the state at component mount but before render which as they claim does not cause a flicker but a lot has changed since then in react and in the example I tried the flicker is there.

Comment: draw the text invisibly i.e. visibility:hidden. Measure it, compute whatever you want to compute...

Comment: Looking at your example, my impression is that the flickering you are complaining about is only a secondary effect compared to the jumps in height for the text blocks. Wouldn't it be preferable to have a smooth transition? It is possible to animate `viewBox` with [SMIL](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/). If you are interested, I could provide an answer spelling this out.

Comment: How much is the difference between a short and a long text. Maybe you could give some examples. Did you have a look at the attributes textLength and lengthAdjust?

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried the visibility thing and it still flashes though i'm not sure anymore if there is any flash due to layout jumping or it is entirely the visibility being toggled but the flash is still present and detectable. Link to sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bbox-svg-text-contain-fill-render-after-calculation-nq00wx)

Comment: @chrwahl I have not heard of those until now and after checking them out they are not what I'm looking for. The text cannot be squeezed or overlayed partially it has to be layout like any other normal text the way it is in the example sandbox.

Comment: @chrwahl Also as for the difference between short and long text - theoretically there is no practical upper limit but the text should be in one line and it could be from 1 to 12 characters most often probably. The example sandbox has character ranges from 7-16. Had to do another comment since you can't edit after 5 min and i forgot this the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best compromise I've found so far is to just make the SVG's visibility hidden and measure the bbox of the text first and show it when done. Then every time the text changes measure again. Generally speaking this should not be too crazy in terms of jumping around or any other visual quirks but for best results you'd want to set a certain fixed size box for the SVG to fill up and not cause any layout shift.

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export type BBox = { x: number; y: number; width: number; height: number };

const makeViewBox = (bbox: BBox) => {
  return `${bbox.x} ${bbox.y} ${bbox.width} ${bbox.height}`;
};

// Note that this component still sometimes jiggles around a bit
// and it is particularly noticable with nont monospaced fonts.

const ScalableSVGText = ({ text }: { text: string }) => {
  // Reference to the SVG element, needed to take bbox measurements
  // and adjust the SVG's viewBox
  const ref = useRef<null | SVGSVGElement>(null);

  // State is somewhat needed to force re-render - other methods
  // can be used but whatever...
  const [bbox, setbbox] = useState<null | BBox>(null);

  // On initial mount & every time the text changes measure the
  // bbox and update the state so the component re-renders
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      setbbox(ref.current.getBBox());
    }
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <svg
      ref={ref}
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      viewBox={bbox ? makeViewBox(bbox) : ""}
      style={{
        // not strictly needed but makes it somwehat easier on the eyes
        visibility: bbox ? "visible" : "hidden"
      }}
    >
      <text>{text}</text>
    </svg>
  );
};

export default ScalableSVGText;
```